# Executing multiple functions in the onPress function with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, onpress

I am currently in the process of creating a naughts and crosses game. I am close to completion, the icons are displayed in the boxes when I clock on any of the boxes. However, I can only display one, naughts or crosses. My code so far: [My App.js script and the component for each box in the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Ly0.png)

My app.Js script is used to manage that state that determines the turn, and a function that changes the state every time a box is pressed is created in the App.js file and passed as props to the Box.js file. Furthermore, a function that displays naught or a cross is in the Box.js file. When I want to pass either of these functions to the onPress function then they work perfectly fine. It's only when I try to put these functions together that problems start arising.

This is what I have tried: `onPress= {() => {props.swicthTurn; Change;}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: *"This is what I have tried: `onPress= {() => {props.swicthTurn; Change;}`"* If those are functions, you're just referring to them, you're not *calling* them. You'd need `()` after them to call them: `onPress= {() => {props.swicthTurn(); Change();}` (but I suspect `Change()` isn't a freestanding function, you probably need to have `x.` in front of it, where `x` is the object you want to call that method on.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the two functions instead of just passing them

```
onPress= {() => {
    props.swicthTurn();
    Change();
}
```

when you pass a function into the `onPress` prop by name it will call it for you, but when you pass in an inline function, you have to execute any sub-functions you might use.

Also, if either of those functions need the event variable that would be passed to them on their own, you need to pass in that variable manually:

```
onPress= {e => {
    props.swicthTurn(e);
    Change(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use onPress = {() => {props.swictchTurn(); Change();}
You should give function to onPress and `{() => {}}` is function declaration. You should call the subfunctions inside this.